# Role of "cavities" in quantum light absorption

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, cavity-qed

I am currently studying the basics of Quantum Electrodynamics, and I have learned from this that photons are the quanta of excitation for given field modes. In other words, when a photon is absorbed, the amplitude of oscillation at that frequency for the EM field goes down by a fixed amount. However, when I imagine a solar panel absorbing photons of light from the sun, it seems to me that rather than shading the area directly behind it, the solar panel should make the entire sun a tiny bit dimmer, since all of Earth's atmosphere is in the same "cavity". Can anyone explain my misconception here? More generally, how do we determine what the "cavity" is when dealing with realistic situations in quantum electrodynamics?

Comment: It is the entire universe's worth of space at the detection timeslice loses a tiny amount of amplitude. Don't worry about it. It is quite silly.

Comment: QED describes the vacuum. If you want to build geometry with QED then you either have to calculate matter properly or cheat. This is why TEO kind of approaches are basically useless in physics.